# Get the difference between two sets from database

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, peewee

Hello beautiful people!

I have created a script where I have two database functions (Feed and Product) where I have a list of Feeds in a store and a list of Product in the store. What I have done is that I am pulling from database every 60 seconds to get all Feeds & Products and see if there is a new URL that has been added or even removed. I have done it by doing something like this:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

from loguru import logger

from lib.database import Feed, Product
from vendors.feed_page import FeedPage
from vendors.product_page import ProductPage


def main() -> None:
    feed_urls: set[str] = set()  # Set of urls to monitor
    product_urls: set[str] = set()  # Set of urls to monitor

    while True:
        db_urls = Feed.get_feeds(1)  # Get from database where id equals store_id
        diff = db_urls - feed_urls  # Get the difference between the two sets
        feed_urls &= db_urls  # Set the urls to the intersection of the two sets
        feed_urls |= db_urls  # Set the urls to the union of the two sets

        # Start threads for each url in the difference
        for url in diff:
            logger.info(f'Adding to Feed monitor: {url}')
            Thread(
                target=FeedPage(url, store_id, feed_urls.__contains__).do_request
            ).start()

        db_urls = Product.get_visible_products(1)
        diff = db_urls - product_urls
        product_urls &= db_urls
        product_urls |= db_urls

        # Start threads for each url in the difference
        for url in diff:
            logger.info(f'Adding to Product monitor: {url}')
            Thread(
                target=ProductPage(url, store_id, product_urls.__contains__).do_request
            ).start()
            break

        time.sleep(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What the program does is that it gets all the URLS from `Feed.get_feeds(store_id)` and compares it with `feed_urls` and whenever there is a difference, we shoot a thread to monitor that specific URL to later in the project see if there is something wrong or other things (Not important for this review)

This is the database call I am also doing by using Peewee as ORM:

```
from loguru import logger
from peewee import (
    Model,
    TextField,
    BooleanField,
    IntegrityError
)
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlDatabase

from config import configuration

# Create a database connection pool.
postgres_pool = PooledPostgresqlDatabase(
    configuration.postgresql.database,
    host=configuration.postgresql.host,
    user=configuration.postgresql.user,
    password=configuration.postgresql.password,
    stale_timeout=30,
)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class Product(Model):
    store_id = TextField(column_name='store_id')
    url = TextField(column_name='url')
    visible = BooleanField(column_name='visible')

    class Meta:
        database = postgres_pool
        db_table = "product"

    @classmethod
    def get_visible_products(cls) -> set:
        try:
            query = cls.select(cls.url).where((cls.store_id == 1) & cls.visible)
            return set(url for url, in query.tuples().iterator())
        except IntegrityError as err:
            logger.info(f'[Product -> get_visible_products] threw error {err}')
            postgres_pool.rollback()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class Feed(Model):
    store_id = TextField(column_name='store_id')
    url = TextField(column_name='url')

    class Meta:
        database = postgres_pool
        db_table = "feed"

    @classmethod
    def get_feeds(cls) -> set:
        try:
            query = cls.select(cls.url).where(cls.store_id == 1)
            return set(url for url, in query.tuples().iterator())

        except IntegrityError as err:
            logger.info(f'[get_feeds] threw error {err}')
            postgres_pool.rollback()
```

It is fairly simple and I hope I am able to get some review regarding my code.... a thing I am not satisfied about is that I am doing the same kind of check to see whenever there is a new url or removed url from the database both for feed and product, perhaps its possible to somehow do it as a function instead? Hopefully I can get an extra eye for this,

Thanks :)